# Avoiding requests for cached files

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control

I have web-server, which store page.html and style.css files. When I try to open IP_ADDRESS/index.html in a browser, then the browser sends two requests to web-server consistently. First request for page.html, second for style.css, which is needs for page.html. I would like to cache style.css in client browser for as long as possible. For that I insert line in header like this:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000, immutable
```

When I try to open page.html in browser, I see two requests first time, which have status 200 for both. Next times, when I open page.html, I also see two requests, but request to page.html has status 200, and request to style.css has status 304.

I sniffed traffic by Wireshark and even tried Burp Suite to scan http requests/responses, and I saw the next picture:

- First connection to web-server: for first request to page.html I obtain "200 OK" response, for second request to style.css I obtain "200 OK" response.
- Second connection to web-page: for first request to page.html I obtain "200 OK" response, for second request (there is header `If-Modified-Since`) to style.css I obtain "304 Not Modified" response.

But problem is, that the second request to style.css sends anyway. I need to fully get rid of it, because client browser already has this file. Tell me please, what should I add to response headers of style.css to avoid any requests to this file, while client browser has cache of style.css file. I would like to see, when in first time client get page.html and style.css files, save style.css in local browser cache, and the next time client only requests page.html without style.css, which client gets from local cache.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What's the browser you used to check this? Chrome? Chrome seem to do this (sending a validation request for cached responses).

Comment: @Pubudu, I've tried both Firefox and Chrome. But I would like to have working solution for popular browsers, including mobile versions. Is there really no solution to add some response headers to specify client browser to use their own cache without checking its modification?

Comment: Ideally, the client should be looking up from the cache unless 1) it's explicitly told not to do so (e.g., `no-cache` directive) 2) the response is stale and it's not allowed to be served stale

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482573/chrome-refuses-to-cache-the-main-html is somewhat similar to your issue..